Raspberry PI 5 Running Debian Trixie No HDMI output
I have a new Raspberry Pi 5 for ref cat /etc/os-release is
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_CODENAME=trixie
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

If I remove the SD Card and boo the pi up I get the boot screen outputting. However, once I put the sdcard back in (128gb Samsung) there is no output.
I have tried 2x different micro HDMI to HDMI cables. Once fomr Amazon and 2x form the thepihut.com (2m and 5m varients).
Based on the forums I have added to /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
video=HDMI-A-1:1280x720@60D
and to /boot/firmware/config.txt added;
dtparam=i2c_arm=on          # Enable I2C interface
dtparam=spi=on              # Enable SPI interface
core_freq=250               # Core frequency
core_freq_min=250

# Force HDMI output and set resolution
hdmi_force_hotplug=1        # Force HDMI even if no display is detected
hdmi_group=1                # Use CEA (TV/projector) mode
hdmi_mode=4                 # Set the resolution to 1280x720 @ 60Hz
hdmi_drive=2                # Enable HDMI with sound (set to 1 for no sound)
disable_overscan=1          # Disable overscan to prevent black borders
config_hdmi_boost=9         # Boost HDMI signal strength (adjust if needed)

I am outputting to a Philips neopix Prime One - which is recognising the output when connecting (its not saying no signal) and I get that it thinks it is outputting 1920x1080p@60hz in a box in the top right hand corner - but nothing else is displayed?
Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

how did you get trixie on the pi? upgrade? since there's no raspberry pi trixie image, I'm assuming so. Raspberry Pi's don't upgrade major debian releases - even after 12 years, the boffins at raspberry pi foundation haven't figured out how to manage that properly

Correct, I had flashed the sdcard using the raspberry pi imager, then upgraded as I wasnt getting any joy. I have managed to get the pi to output the the projector by adding dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d to /boot/firmware/config.txt. However, the pi still does not recognise there is a display and xrandr returns can't open display. Could this cause problems? Is it possible to roll back the update?
